# Displaying exception message to view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, view, controller

I have difficulties displaying exception message from controller to view.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BlankTemplate(string startyear, string endyear, string templatetype,DownloadTemplateViewModel dm)
        {
           try
           { 
              // Do Something
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
             ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
             return View(dm);
           }
           Return View()
    }
```

View:

```
<table>
   Validation.summary(false)
</table>
```

any help?

I am using the same view.

and the exception occurs at the same time as HttpPost.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you need to change

```
Validation.summary(false)
```

to

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

First approach
You can use different approach which is best for you
1)add this namespace in viewpage

```
 @model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
```

2nd approach

```
1)<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
2)[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(DbUpdateException), View = "Error")]
    public class BlankController : Controller
    {
   // your action is here 
}
```